# memory mapped file write failed in SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication, sql-server-2019, transactional-replication

I am getting the error "memory mapped file write failed" while trying to run Snap Shot Agent in Transactional Replication. Snap shot works fine if the table is having only a few hundreds of rows. And fails if the table contains few thousands of rows. The SQL Server is installed on a Linux Server and tried many suggestions found online. But to no avail. Can anyone please guide me on this.

[Screen shot of Transaction Replication Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8BjE.png)

Comment: Maybe check your hard disk for bad blocks and other failing conditions.

Comment: No bad blocks found.

Comment: I have encountered this issue too just now. Also running SQL Server in a container trying to configure transactional replication. I haven't found any help. We may have to go back to running SQL on Windows

Comment: A different thread in SO mentioned that it seemed to be a new problem with CU9 (they rolled back to CU8 and it worked).

Comment: I have an open case with MS on it. They've been able to reproduce it with AdventureWorks, and are currently still investigating.  Possible workaround: roll back to CU8.

Answer (score 0):

We've also had a similar issue with **Snapshot Replication**. As a workaround, we split the replication into multiple publications. After several trials, we were able to successfully replicate our database which contains more than 1000 tables with 5 publications. *Except for 1 table with a text column (containing big xml), maybe we need another workaround in this case.*

If you are only replicating 1 large table, you might try splitting it using Filter Rows.

We are using **SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition** on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** Server Linux Container with **8GB RAM**. Other databases are installed on this server: *MySQL 8.0*, *MariaDB 10.5*, and *PostgreSQL 12.5*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying with a single table in a single publication. Even with filters applied there are cases with large number of rows in a table.